# Website moves when going to a different page

Tags: php, html, css

my website http://www.oblivionro.net/ has a problem where it moves down a bit when visiting a different page. For instance, when visiting the "Rules" page from the main website, the container "moves" down a bit.

Anyone know what might be causing this? I can't seem to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Believe it or not..

..the problem is that the homepage has this in a different place to where the "Rules" page does:

```
    <p>
      <!--<strong>Powered by Flux Control Panel ... -->
    </p>
    <p>
      <!--Page generated in <strong>0.3699</strong> ... -->
    </p>
```

Even though that's *near the end* of your page, it's causing the problem - specifically: the `margin-top` on those `p` elements is. Welcome to the wonders of [collapsing margins](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins).

The simplest way to fix this is to remove the `<p>` tags that wrap the comments.

Comment: +1 By the way, these empty paragraphs exist in the main page as well, but inside `#cont_box` instead of after it...

Comment: Thanks, you're completely right. I didn't know it did that and I appreciate your help!